# Get the name of all term which is duplicate using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am coding something to get all duplicate term which has duplicate name using a mysql query. The issue I have currently is I am getting the records in a single occurrence I need all data which has the same name.

I am running this query.

```
SELECT a.*,COUNT(name) AS occurrences 
            FROM wp_terms AS a 
            INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS b ON a.term_id = b.term_id  
            WHERE b.taxonomy = "ticker"
            GROUP BY a.name HAVING occurrences > 1'
```

Current result

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 13872
            [name] => AAV
            [slug] => aav
            [term_group] => 0
            [occurrences] => 2
        )
```

Expected result

```
[0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [term_id] => 13872
                [name] => AAV
                [slug] => aav
                [term_group] => 0
                [occurrences] => 2
            )
    [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [term_id] => 13873
                [name] => AAV
                [slug] => aav-2
                [term_group] => 0
                [occurrences] => 2
            )
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the matching rows using window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.name) as cnt
      FROM wp_terms t JOIN
           wp_term_taxonomy tt
           ON t.term_id = tt.term_id  
      WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'ticker'
    ) t
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt DESC, name;
```

EDIT:

There are various approaches in older versions of MySQL.  One is:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt
        WHERE tt.term_id = t.term_id AND
              tt.taxonomy = 'ticker'
    ) t
FROM wp_terms t
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt DESC, name;
```

Comment: getting empty result

Comment: @TejasGajjar . . . Oops.  I left the `GROUP BY` in.

Comment: Still empty result @Gordon.

Comment: I think there is an MySql error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY t.name) "

Comment: @TejasGajjar . . . Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8+.

Comment: Any other way to do it except upgrading to 8.0?